# Can't list the files in GCS bucket in command-line using Hadoop GCS connector

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, google-cloud-dataproc

I had the GCS connector already installed in Spark. Last week I followed the instructions on [INSTALL.md](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/master/gcs/INSTALL.md) to install the connector in Hadoop. (Note: I'm using the same service account and it is working fine in Spark)

When I'm trying to list the files in a GCS bucket via the command-line, I'm getting this exception `com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$DecodingException: Unrecognized character: /`

Here are the commands I'm executing

```sh
$ hadoop fs -ls gs://dp-druid-ingestion
-ls: com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$DecodingException: Unrecognized character: /
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options]
    [-appendToFile <localsrc> ... <dst>]
    [-cat [-ignoreCrc] <src> ...]
    [-checksum <src> ...]
    [-chgrp [-R] GROUP PATH...]
    [-chmod [-R] <MODE[,MODE]... | OCTALMODE> PATH...]
    [-chown [-R] [OWNER][:[GROUP]] PATH...]
    [-copyFromLocal [-f] [-p] [-l] [-d] [-t <thread count>] <localsrc> ... <dst>]
    [-copyToLocal [-f] [-p] [-ignoreCrc] [-crc] <src> ... <localdst>]
    [-count [-q] [-h] [-v] [-t [<storage type>]] [-u] [-x] [-e] <path> ...]
    [-cp [-f] [-p | -p[topax]] [-d] <src> ... <dst>]
    [-createSnapshot <snapshotDir> [<snapshotName>]]
    [-deleteSnapshot <snapshotDir> <snapshotName>]
    [-df [-h] [<path> ...]]
    [-du [-s] [-h] [-v] [-x] <path> ...]
    [-expunge]
    [-find <path> ... <expression> ...]
    [-get [-f] [-p] [-ignoreCrc] [-crc] <src> ... <localdst>]
    [-getfacl [-R] <path>]
    [-getfattr [-R] {-n name | -d} [-e en] <path>]
    [-getmerge [-nl] [-skip-empty-file] <src> <localdst>]
    [-head <file>]
    [-help [cmd ...]]
    [-ls [-C] [-d] [-h] [-q] [-R] [-t] [-S] [-r] [-u] [-e] [<path> ...]]
    [-mkdir [-p] <path> ...]
    [-moveFromLocal <localsrc> ... <dst>]
    [-moveToLocal <src> <localdst>]
    [-mv <src> ... <dst>]
    [-put [-f] [-p] [-l] [-d] <localsrc> ... <dst>]
    [-renameSnapshot <snapshotDir> <oldName> <newName>]
    [-rm [-f] [-r|-R] [-skipTrash] [-safely] <src> ...]
    [-rmdir [--ignore-fail-on-non-empty] <dir> ...]
    [-setfacl [-R] [{-b|-k} {-m|-x <acl_spec>} <path>]|[--set <acl_spec> <path>]]
    [-setfattr {-n name [-v value] | -x name} <path>]
    [-setrep [-R] [-w] <rep> <path> ...]
    [-stat [format] <path> ...]
    [-tail [-f] <file>]
    [-test -[defsz] <path>]
    [-text [-ignoreCrc] <src> ...]
    [-touchz <path> ...]
    [-truncate [-w] <length> <path> ...]
    [-usage [cmd ...]]

Generic options supported are:
-conf <configuration file>        specify an application configuration file
-D <property=value>               define a value for a given property
-fs <file:///|hdfs://namenode:port> specify default filesystem URL to use, overrides 'fs.defaultFS' property from configurations.
-jt <local|resourcemanager:port>  specify a ResourceManager
-files <file1,...>                specify a comma-separated list of files to be copied to the map reduce cluster
-libjars <jar1,...>               specify a comma-separated list of jar files to be included in the classpath
-archives <archive1,...>          specify a comma-separated list of archives to be unarchived on the compute machines

The general command line syntax is:
command [genericOptions] [commandOptions]

Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -ls [-C] [-d] [-h] [-q] [-R] [-t] [-S] [-r] [-u] [-e] [<path> ...]
```

```sh
$ hdfs dfs -ls gs://dp-druid-ingestion
-ls: com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$DecodingException: Unrecognized character: /
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options]
    [-appendToFile <localsrc> ... <dst>]
    [-cat [-ignoreCrc] <src> ...]
    [-checksum <src> ...]
    [-chgrp [-R] GROUP PATH...]
    [-chmod [-R] <MODE[,MODE]... | OCTALMODE> PATH...]
    [-chown [-R] [OWNER][:[GROUP]] PATH...]
    [-copyFromLocal [-f] [-p] [-l] [-d] [-t <thread count>] <localsrc> ... <dst>]
    [-copyToLocal [-f] [-p] [-ignoreCrc] [-crc] <src> ... <localdst>]
    [-count [-q] [-h] [-v] [-t [<storage type>]] [-u] [-x] [-e] <path> ...]
    [-cp [-f] [-p | -p[topax]] [-d] <src> ... <dst>]
    [-createSnapshot <snapshotDir> [<snapshotName>]]
    [-deleteSnapshot <snapshotDir> <snapshotName>]
    [-df [-h] [<path> ...]]
    [-du [-s] [-h] [-v] [-x] <path> ...]
    [-expunge]
    [-find <path> ... <expression> ...]
    [-get [-f] [-p] [-ignoreCrc] [-crc] <src> ... <localdst>]
    [-getfacl [-R] <path>]
    [-getfattr [-R] {-n name | -d} [-e en] <path>]
    [-getmerge [-nl] [-skip-empty-file] <src> <localdst>]
    [-head <file>]
    [-help [cmd ...]]
    [-ls [-C] [-d] [-h] [-q] [-R] [-t] [-S] [-r] [-u] [-e] [<path> ...]]
    [-mkdir [-p] <path> ...]
    [-moveFromLocal <localsrc> ... <dst>]
    [-moveToLocal <src> <localdst>]
    [-mv <src> ... <dst>]
    [-put [-f] [-p] [-l] [-d] <localsrc> ... <dst>]
    [-renameSnapshot <snapshotDir> <oldName> <newName>]
    [-rm [-f] [-r|-R] [-skipTrash] [-safely] <src> ...]
    [-rmdir [--ignore-fail-on-non-empty] <dir> ...]
    [-setfacl [-R] [{-b|-k} {-m|-x <acl_spec>} <path>]|[--set <acl_spec> <path>]]
    [-setfattr {-n name [-v value] | -x name} <path>]
    [-setrep [-R] [-w] <rep> <path> ...]
    [-stat [format] <path> ...]
    [-tail [-f] <file>]
    [-test -[defsz] <path>]
    [-text [-ignoreCrc] <src> ...]
    [-touchz <path> ...]
    [-truncate [-w] <length> <path> ...]
    [-usage [cmd ...]]

Generic options supported are:
-conf <configuration file>        specify an application configuration file
-D <property=value>               define a value for a given property
-fs <file:///|hdfs://namenode:port> specify default filesystem URL to use, overrides 'fs.defaultFS' property from configurations.
-jt <local|resourcemanager:port>  specify a ResourceManager
-files <file1,...>                specify a comma-separated list of files to be copied to the map reduce cluster
-libjars <jar1,...>               specify a comma-separated list of jar files to be included in the classpath
-archives <archive1,...>          specify a comma-separated list of archives to be unarchived on the compute machines

The general command line syntax is:
command [genericOptions] [commandOptions]

Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -ls [-C] [-d] [-h] [-q] [-R] [-t] [-S] [-r] [-u] [-e] [<path> ...]
```

### Cluster info.

- Hadoop version: v3.1.0
- GCS connector version: v2.1.4
- Using Dataproc: No, I'm using on premise Hadoop.

Comment: A few questions? What are the Hadoop and connector versions? Are you running on Dataproc?

Comment: Good question @DavidRabinowitz I've updated the question body.

Comment: Did you print HADOOP_CLASSPATH to make sure the path to GCS connector jar is actually included?

Comment: 1) Are you using Hadoop 3 version of GCS connector? 2) May you list content of this bucket using gsutil (`gsutil ls gs://dp-druid-ingestion`)? 3) May you try to repro this in Dataproc cluster to understand if it Hadoop env-issue or GCS connector?

Comment: 4) May you run this command with debug logging as mentioned in [troubleshooting instructions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/master/gcs/INSTALL.md#troubleshooting-the-installation)?